# PowerShell variables in Arrays with Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, exchange-server-2010

I've been researching how to add and remove user mailbox Safe Senders and Safe Recipients in bulk with Exchange 2010. Seems like there is more information for small scale or single entry implementation, but I cannot get things to full translate to a larger scale.

Adding to Safe Senders/Recipients works fine with this:

```
#Test file with single entry
$testsites = (gc C:\temp\testsites.txt)

(get-mailbox -identity *) | foreach-object {set-mailboxjunkemailconfiguration -identity $_.alias -trustedsendersanddomains @{add=$testsites}}
```

My problem is with removing. To my knowledge, adjusting to the script below should work, but does not:

```
(get-mailbox -identity *) | foreach-object {set-mailboxjunkemailconfiguration -identity $_.alias -trustedsendersanddomains @{remove=$testsites}}
```

Placing the entry content of the file in quotes, and using remove does work:

```
(get-mailbox -identity *) | foreach-object {set-mailboxjunkemailconfiguration -identity $_.alias -trustedsendersanddomains @{remove="@test.com"}}
```

The end goal for this script is to have a CSV with several dozen entries being added or removed to +1000 mailboxes. The get-content or text file usage is very much for testing purposes, so if there are other methods I am all ears. I was just curious if anybody had insight as to why, as written, I can add but cannot remove sites in bulk?

Comment: I'd also be very receptive to any online information pertaining to PS arrays and/or hashtables, and how they handle input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it isn't my favorite solution, I've rewritten the script and have figured out how to remove in bulk. This is sort of a shotgun approach, so I'm not sure if it is anywhere near optimal.

```
#Set what you want to remove (hashtable to variable)
$testsites = Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -Identity $Mailbox.Name -TrustedSendersAndDomains

#Pipe mailbox name properties to Set, and specify Remove
Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -Identity $Mailbox.Name -TrustedSendersAndDomains $Testsites.Remove
```

Confirmed working in multiple development environments.